# Mail multiple ranges as picture in the body of Outlook

Tags: excel, vba, image, outlook

I am trying to email different ranges as pictures from excel to outlook,  [I've attempted Ron Bruins  solution](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail0.htm) but it only allows me to use one range instead of 3 ranges.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_And_JPG_Range_Outlook()
'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
'This macro use the function named : CopyRangeToJPG
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strbody As String
Dim MakeJPG1 As String
Dim MakeJPG2 As String
Dim MakeJPG3 As String

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strbody = "Dear Customer" & "<br><br>" & _
    "Below you find a picture of your data." & "<br>" & _
    "If you need more information let me know." & "<br><br>" & _
    "Regards Ron<br>"
          
'Create JPG file of the range
'Only enter the Sheet name and the range address
MakeJPG1 = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet4", "A4:J30")
MakeJPG2 = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet4", "L4:W10")
MakeJPG3 = CopyRangeToJPG("Sheet4", "X4:AI10")
```

I've added here the 3 different ranges I have, but no luck on  having a positive outcome

Ths one will be part of the function  to copy

```
Function CopyRangeToJPG(NameWorksheet As String, RangeAddress As String) As String
'Ron de Bruin, 25-10-2019
Dim PictureRange As Range
Dim picNumber As String


With ActiveWorkbook
    On Error Resume Next
    .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Activate
    Set PictureRange = .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).Range(RangeAddress)
    
    If PictureRange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sorry this is not a correct range"
        On Error GoTo 0
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    PictureRange.CopyPicture
    With .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Add(PictureRange.Left, PictureRange.Top, PictureRange.Width, PictureRange.Height)
        .Activate
        .Chart.Paste
        .Chart.Export Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg", "JPG"
    End With
    .Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects(.Worksheets(NameWorksheet).ChartObjects.Count).Delete
End With

CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture - " & picNumber & ".jpg"
```

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies in the following line on function CopyRangeToJPG()

```
CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture.jpg"
```

As you can see, the filename is hardcoded and it doesn't allow you to have more than one because having the same filename would replace the previous file.
A quick and dirty way to fix it is to add a third parameter (e.g.: picNumber) and pass it to the function. Then replace it with something like

```
CopyRangeToJPG = Environ$("temp") & Application.PathSeparator & "NamePicture - " & picNumber & ".jpg"
```

Comment: So for the code Sub Mail_small_Text_And_JPG_Range_Outlook () I was in the right track? I just need to replace the original code in  CopyRangeToJPG()  for the one you provided?

Comment: I added a bit of code with the replacement

Comment: Give it a try. But yes, that should be it. Just don't forget to also pass the third parameter with a different number each time. I can't try it so I can't tell if it works or not.